# What is wrong with this method declaration?

Tags: c, methods, boolean

```
bool somemethod(int number){
    return true;
}
```

I keep getting this error message when I try to compile code with this method

```
/Users/user/Desktop/test.c:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘somemethod’
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thing is `bool` isn't a true keyword in C. Include `stdbool.h` if you need it - this should work with C99 implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, bool is not a keyword in C so from the prospective of the compiler you didn't include a return, hence the error.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Should fix your problem, I have been on systems before where it was not possible to include this header file... if you do not want to/can not include stdbool.h you have a few other options:

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef char bool
```

Something along these lines will allow you to continue as normal.